# Faster modeling workflow in 3DS Max

Tags: 3d, workflow, 3ds-max, modeling

As a Blender user for 2 years, I'm very comftoble with its workflow and I found modeling in 3DS Max a bit of a slower process than Blender. For example, Extruding in Blender can be done by hitting "E" with a selected polygon and the new polygon follows the cursor in the direction of the axis specified by a shortcut. The process is the same for moving, scaling and rotating. But, in 3DS Max when hitting a shortcut, there is a visual process for the mouse to achieve a certain operation -

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this to speed up the workflow in that way just like in Blender?

Comment: I'd suggest go back to blender ;) The only real alternative is modo for modeling.

Comment: 3D Questions are no longer in scope on our website through community consensus. There is a proposal for a 3D StackExchange site that could use your support: [3D Graphics, Modeling & Animation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics-modeling-animation).

Answer (score 2):

You can customize any action in 3ds Max with your shortcut of preference.

In main menu go to **Customize->Costumize User Interface->Keyboard**
and find there Extrude(Poly) then assign a keyboard shortcut combination.

[image]

I know this question is very old, but I couldn't let it unanswered ;)